# Using jQuery or ASP.NET, how to download page and then asynchrously download images on page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Using jQuery or ASP.NET, how to download page and then asynchrously download images on page? Let's say on the page you have a gallery of multiple images grabbed from your database and you want to download page first, and then wait for the images to download asynchrously while displaying some sort of ajax-loader.gif sign. I wonder how it's done?

Comment: here is an article for lazy loading http://engineering.slideshare.net/2011/03/faster-page-loads-with-image-lazy-loading/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402680/jquery-javascript-html-how-to-load-images-after-everything-else-is-loaded see if this old post from SO help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jQuery to load the images async?
http://idesignow.com/jquery/10-jquery-image-loader-plugins-tutorials-generators.html