# Loading certain images upon certain events (not on page load)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, performance, load

Is there a way in JS/jQuery to "block" the loading of certain images in the DOM, up until a certain event occurs?

In my case, I have a page of products (WooCommerce Shop page) where clicking a product opens a modal window containing the image gallery of that particular product. But instead of loading galleries of all products on page load (too slow) I'd like to bind the loading of the image gallery to the opening of the modal window.

I'm guessing it's not really possible but perhaps there's some trick that comes close?

Comment: Add an `img` element in your modal window without `src` attribute and update the `src` attribute when you select a product

Comment: Exactly, just found the trick elsewhere. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `img` element in your modal window without any `src` attribute and update the `src` attribute based on the product selection.

Here's a [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QydbmJ) showcasing the idea :)

Comment: I answered probably while you were finishing your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

A satisfying way to achieve the same end result is to sabotage the `src` attribute of images, and then restore this attribute later on with JS.

Found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5402812/871404 (thanks @arkantos too!)

Comment: yea.. also, instead of `lsrc` you might want to do something like `data-src` or something. More meaningful as a HTML5 data attribute that nothing.